# Connecting to BigQuery using ODBC in Qlikview

Tags: odbc, google-bigquery, qlikview, qliksense

I have the latest BigQuery ODBC driver installed and setup according to the [instruction here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/)

I was able to follow the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/11/how-to-connect-bigquery-to-microsoft-excel-and-other-apps-with-our-new-odbc-driver) and access the data in MS Excel.

However in Qlikview I was unable to see any tables when using the same ODBC connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODBC driver is functional. What I didn't notice was that I didn't have any dataset created under the BigQuery test project, hence no table was available.

It is still possible to utilize QlikView to access the public data set by adding the query strings in the scripts after the ODBC CONNECT line.

[QlikView Edit Script screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYnSA.png)